# How do I return a value from 2 overloaded functions with different return types?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I created two functions to import (make) an array from a text file. They have the same function names but different number of parameters. They also have return values which are different since one importArray function is returning a 1D array and the other is returning a 2D array.

```
Overloads Function importArray(fileName As String) As Array

Overloads Function importArray(fileName As String, splitter As Char) As Array

Sub Main()
        Dim getArray As New MakeArray
        Dim printArray() As String = getArray.importArray("array.txt")

        For i = 0 To printArray.Length - 1
            'printArray
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I can enter 2 parameters when calling the function or 1 then it's fine, but I don't know how I could specify which function to call, because when I am printing the array I don't know whether to use the 1D or 2D array. I can't do 2 for loops since using one dimension or 2 throws an error "Expression is not a method" so I'm not sure how I can get around this.

Is there a way I could determine whether I am using a 1D or 2D array by reading the text file? I wanted to keep the code as efficient as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: If the difference in the arrays is that one is in effect an array of the other, then perhaps making a Class which has properties that match the columns and using a List(Of thatClass) would make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't use the `Array` type that way.  If the method return `String` array, that should be the return type.  If it returns a 2D `String` array then that should be the return type.

```
Overloads Function ImportArray(fileName As String) As String()

Overloads Function ImportArray(fileName As String, splitter As Char) As String(,)
```

When you call one of the functions, you assign it to a variable of the appropriate type for the method you're calling.  Just think of them as two different methods.  Then, you either use a single loop of two nested loops to traverse the data.

```
Dim arr1 As String() = getArray.ImportArray(fileName)

For i = 0 To arr1.GetUpperBound(0)
    '...
Next

Dim arr2 As String(,) = getArray.ImportArray(fileName, splitter)

For i = 0 To arr2.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To arr2.GetUpperBound(1)
        '...
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Ohhhh, that makes a lot of sense. Went straight over my head. Thanks a lot!